# Office 365 Active Directory with Local TFS

Tags: active-directory, team-foundation-server, microsoft-office-365

We want to purchase Office 365 service with Active Directory and use the online AD for our company computers and also TFS accounts of developers. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No. You need a local instance of Active Directory for computer joins and similar. However, this instance can be synced with the Office365/Azure directory for single-sign on and simplified account management.